# How to write a script in Python to take a file as input with Solana addresses and send them same amount of SOL to each one?

Tags: python, transactions, send, solana

Can someone please help to write a script take a file with many Solana addresses and send the same SOL amount to each address.

I am trying to automate a manual process which is taking forever.

Please be kind to help.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Python script that sends SOL to a list of addresses, you'll first need to accept the list as input, likely using something like ArgParse: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

You'll have to read the file: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

After that, you'll need to create a bunch of `transfer` instructions: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/07ec29e51d47b3989f3d516032b76098b9f950e3/src/solana/system_program.py#L388

Finally, you'll need to create, sign, and send transactions that contain the instructions, example of that here: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/07ec29e51d47b3989f3d516032b76098b9f950e3/tests/integration/test_async_http_client.py#L70

If you're ok with using something existing, however, `solana-tokens` already has this logic implemented for you! Check out https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/tokens#distribute-tokens-transfer-amount for how to use it